# Win32 strange widechar behavior

Tags: c++, windows, wchar

I haven't used wide chars before.  Here's the code from someone else:

```
char moduleFileName[512];
int size = ::GetModuleFileName(NULL,moduleFileName,sizeof(moduleFileName));
char c_drive[256];
char c_dir[256];
_splitpath_s(moduleFileName,c_drive,sizeof(c_drive),c_dir,sizeof(c_dir),NULL,0,NULL,0);
root = c_drive;
root.append(c_dir);

wchar_t moduleFileNameW[512];
int sizeW = ::GetModuleFileNameW(NULL,moduleFileNameW,sizeof(moduleFileNameW));
wchar_t w_drive[256];
wchar_t w_dir[256];
_wsplitpath_s(moduleFileNameW,w_drive,sizeof(w_drive),w_dir,sizeof(w_dir),NULL,0,NULL,0);
wroot = w_drive;
wroot.append(w_dir);

SEVEN_ZIP_EXE = wroot;
SEVEN_ZIP_EXE += L"\\7z.exe";
```

The point is to set a variable to where the 7z.exe file is.  When I debug it on my Windows 7 Prof. 64 bit system I end up what look to me like invalid chars for wroot, e.g.

> ﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌
>   Blockquote

Comment: Is SEVEN_ZIP_EXE an std::wstring?

Comment: The behaviour is probably strange because the code sure is

Comment: std::wstring SEVEN_ZIP_EXE = L"";

Comment: One problem you have is using sizeof for the W functions. That is not good. They want the number of elements in the array not the size in bytes.

Comment: Why is all the widechar stuff neeeded anyway?  Any reason I can't just calculate the path in the first block of functions?

Comment: The debug dump is trying to show you the Unicode glyph for 0xfefefefe.  Plenty of meaning for that value: http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html

Comment: "쳌" is 0xCCCC and that is mostly because you haven't initialized the variables. 0xFE in the remaining part is buffer slack. It appears in [MSVC debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new) and is extremely useful to determine the bug when you see some "strange" values such as the string above, int3 (software interrupt), invalid access to address 0xCCCCCCCC, or 204, -858993460, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Change your sizeof's to _countof's and that will fix your strange data problem.

You don't need both sets of functions. Use whichever set is appropriate for the application.
If you need SEVEN_ZIP_EXE to be a wstring, then you can eliminate the char stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sizeof, and if you really want to use this sizeof(w_dir)/sizeof(wchar_t)

I gather what you are trying to do is get the directory containing your executable.
Rather than using the clumsy splitpath, I suggest the following:-

```
TCHAR   szBuff[FILENAME_MAX];
TCHAR   *ShortName;
GetFullPathName(moduleFileName, FILENAME_MAX, szBuff, &ShortName);
*(ShortName-1) = '\0';  // remove exe from path
```

szBuff will contain the directory, and ShortName points to the name.

The above code uses TCHAR and #define UNICODE, but you could change the functions names to the wchar names.

Comment: It is poor coding to use FILENAME_MAX in the function call. It is better to use the Microsoft defined macro on the variable, _countof(szBuff). That way if FILENAME_MAX has to be changed it doesn't need to be changed in multiple places.

Comment: FILENAME_MAX is a system defined constant

Comment: What if someone changes the size of szBuff to something other than FILENAME_MAX? What if an SDK update changes the value of FILENAME_MAX?